# Bash file descriptors vs Linux file descriptors

Tags: linux, bash

I'm just trying to reconcile these two seemingly similar concepts.

In Bash, one is allowed to make arbitrary redirections, and importantly, using one's chosen file descriptor number. However in Linux, the value returned by an `open` call (AFAIK) cannot be chosen by the calling process.

Thus, are Bash fd numbers the same as the fd numbers returned by system calls? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little experiment that might shed some light on what's going on when you open a file descriptor in bash with a number of your choosing:

```
> cat test.txt
foobar!

> cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
exec 17<test.txt
read -u 17 line
echo "$line"
exec 17>&-

> strace ./test.sh
//// A bunch of stuff omitted so we can skip to the interesting part...
open("test.txt", O_RDONLY)              = 3
fcntl(17, F_GETFD)                      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
dup2(3, 17)                             = 17
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(17, F_GETFD)                      = 0
ioctl(17, TCGETS, 0x7ffc56f093f0)       = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(17, 0, SEEK_CUR)                  = 0
read(17, "foobar!\n", 128)              = 8
write(1, "foobar!\n", 8foobar!)         = 8
fcntl(17, F_GETFD)                      = 0
fcntl(17, F_DUPFD, 10)                  = 10
fcntl(17, F_GETFD)                      = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
close(17)                               = 0
```

The part that answers your question is where it calls `open()` on `test.txt`, which returns a value of 3. This is what you would most likely get in a C program if you did the same, because file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 (i.e., `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`) are all you have open initially. The number 3 is just the next available file descriptor.

And we see that in the `strace` output of the bash script as well. What bash does differently is that it then calls `fcntl(17, F_GETFD)` to check if file descriptor 17 is already open (because it wants to use that fd for `test.txt`). Then, when `fcntl` returns `EBADF` indicating no such fd is open, bash knows it is free to use it. So then it calls `dup2(3, 17)` to make fd 17 a copy of fd 3. Finally, it calls `close()` on fd 3 to free it up again, leaving fd 17 (and *only* fd 17) as an open file descriptor for `test.txt`.

So the answer to your question is that bash file descriptors are not special creatures set apart from the "normal" file descriptors that everyone else uses. They are in fact just the same thing. You could easily use the same trick in your C program to open files with file descriptor numbers of your choosing.

Also, it's worth pointing out that bash doesn't really get to choose its own file descriptor when it calls `open()`. It has to make do with whatever `open()` returns, like everyone else. All that's really going on in your bash script is some smoke and mirrors (via `dup2()`) to make it seem as if you get to choose your own file descriptor.